# Unable to run python script by name

Tags: python, runtime

WORKING CODE

**etu$ ./mynotes.py new fff**

CALLING MAIN

======================================

NOT WORKING CODE

**etu$ mynotes.py new fff**

mynotes.py: command not found

=====================================

My mynotes.py has executable permission and its located in current directory but I am not able to execute it without "./" as prefix.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

To run python files in cmd/shell we have to use command `python` or `py` and then with the file name and if the file name has white space then it should be withing double quotes `"file_name"` example.
If the file name is: mynotes.py

```
python mynotes.py
```

If the file name has space like my notes.py

```
python "my notes.py"
```